# Django urls regex for query string

Tags: regex, django, url, query-string

Following is from urls.py:

```
url(r'^\?view=(?P<vtype>instructor|course|room)$', 'index', name='index'),
```

i can verify that it works by simply calling django.core.urlresolvers.reverse in shell :

```
In [6]: reverse('index', args=["course"])
Out[6]: '/?view=course'
```

but when i try to access http://localhost:8000/?view=course
i get 404.

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks

**Edit:**

```
url('^search/\?user=(?P<userid>\d+)&type=topic', 'search_forum', name='my_topics'),
```

this is from a former project which works as expected. sigh...

Comment: Do you have anything that is supposed to answer for that URL?

Comment: yes, index() normally works without regex. but adding query string regex breaks the url dispatching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Query string is not part of the URL. If you want to do it this way, you have to use `url(r'^$', 'index', name='index')` and then look it up in request.GET dictionary in the view.

The usual way, however, is to use `url(r'(?P<vtype>instructor|course|room)/$', 'index', name='index')`. The querystring approach is the usual workaround for not being able to direct requests according to the non-querystring URL part. Django does not have that limitation.

Answer (score -1):

Your regex matches from the beginning (^) but I don't see anything to match the leading '/'. Could this be it?

Comment: unfortunately not.django url dispatcher resolves the part after the root /. yet i tried if that could be it but no luck :)