# How to frame my url pattern in Django

Tags: python, django, web, django-views, django-urls

> http://localhost:8000/?Input=C%3A%5CUsers%5Crsukla%5CDesktop%5COHA_BPO_Project%5CClear+Capital%5CInput_CC1&Output=3A%5CUsers%5Crsukla%5CDesktop%5COHA_BPO_Project%5CClear+Capital%5CInput_CC1&id=CC1

I want to frame my url pattern such that if the string ends with "id=CC1" then it should go bpo.views.cc1. I am not able to form the url pattern and need help. Below are my url patterns

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Examples:
    url(r'^$', 'bpo.views.cc1', name='cc1'),
    url(r'^$', 'bpo.views.home', name='home'),  # ^$ is for ending the string
    # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),
    #url(r'home2$', 'bpo.views.home', name='home'),   for website ending with home2
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django urls regex for query string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6011146/django-urls-regex-for-query-string)

Comment: [url dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/)